# Multiple actions added to a stage = mess

Tags: action, libgdx, actor

I am using scene2d with actors and a stage.
In my class World I need to add actions to IMAGES to my stage, for example:

```
Image impact;
Texture impactTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/impact.png"));
impact = new Image(impactTexture);
    impact.setPosition(x - impact.getWidth() / 2, y - impact.getHeight() / 2);      
    impact.setTouchable(Touchable.disabled);
    impact.addAction(sequence(fadeOut(0.2f), run(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            impact.remove();
        }
    })));

    stage.addActor(impact);
```

This works fine, the image is displayed and fades out as wanted.
But when I want to add the same action to an ACTOR, the action doesn't work. For example, I am trying to add the action fadeOut to my actor "Loot".

```
Loot loot;  
loot = new Loot(new Vector2(x, y, 0, 0);
    loot.setTouchable(Touchable.disabled);
    Action lootAction = sequence(fadeOut(1f), moveTo(30,30,1), run(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loot.remove();
        }
    }));        
    loot.addAction(lootAction);     
    stage.addActor(loot);
```

And the code of my class Loot:

```
public class Loot extends Actor {

protected Vector2 position;
protected int width; 
protected int height;
protected Rectangle bounds;
protected float rotation;
protected int TYPE; 
protected int amount;
public Boolean movetoinventory = false;

Texture keyTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/key.png"));

public Loot(Vector2 position, float rotation, int TYPE) {

    this.position = position;
    this.width = keyTexture.getWidth();
    this.height = keyTexture.getHeight();
    bounds = new Rectangle(position.x, position.y, width, height);
    this.rotation = rotation;
    this.TYPE = TYPE;
}

public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
    batch.draw(keyTexture, position.x, position.y, width/2, height/2, width, height, 1, 1, rotation, 0, 0, keyTexture.getWidth(), keyTexture.getHeight(), false, false);        
}

public void act(float delta){
super.act(delta);
}
```

Why is the fadeOut action working on an IMAGE and not an ACTOR?

I render everything in a separate class WorldRenderer which has:

```
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the `act` method in your Loot class is empty ?

Try adding `super.act(delta);`.

By the way, you don't need to declare position, width, height... in your class, Actor has already theses fields.

Actions animates actors properties, not your own. You need to modify your code to use the base class properties, like this :

```
public Loot(Vector2 position, float rotation, int TYPE) {

    // set position and size
    setBounds(position.x, position.y, keyTexture.getWidth(), keyTexture.getHeight());
    setRotation(rotation);
    this.TYPE = TYPE;
}

public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
    batch.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, alpha);
    batch.draw(keyTexture, getX(), getY(), getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, getWidth(), getHeight(), 1, 1, rotation, 0, 0, keyTexture.getWidth(), keyTexture.getHeight(), false, false);        
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I was removing part of my code to make my post more readable and forgot super.act(delta);
Now part of the action is working: what is inside the runnable works fine, but not the first part of the sequence (fadeout). Any idea?

Comment: Once again good point... Everything looks good now, except again the first part of the sequence doesn't work:
Action lootAction = sequence(fadeOut(1f), moveTo(30,30,1), run(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loot.remove();
        }
    }));        
I can not see the fading but it is definitely taken into account somewhere because after the duration I set, the runnable part of the action works.
I really don't get it!

Comment: Have you added the line `batch.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, alpha);` in your draw() method ?

Comment: Yes I have added it. I think you are right that is must be an alpha issue. the logic of the sequence seems to work since the runnable is executed. There must be some place where I do something wrong with the alpha of the actor.

Comment: Have you disabled blending ? see this : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch%2C-textureregions%2C-and-sprite at the "Blending" section.

Comment: Hey Aurel, thanks for keeping it up. I'm getting confused now, should the draw method of my Actor has 
batch = new SpriteBatch();

batch.begin(); batch.draw(mystuff); batch.end(); 

?

Comment: Ok most probably I am doing something wrong elsewhere. I don't want to waste your time as without the whole code it's tedious. 
Of course if you have another idea, feel free to post :)
Thanks a lot for your help, I've already progressed thanks to you! Merci beaucoup :)

Comment: If the purpose of your class Loot is mainly to display a texture, why not extends Image instead of Actor ?